# AngularJS $location.path not working as intended

Tags: javascript, angularjs, url, redirect, location

```
var AddCtrl = function($scope, $stateParams, $http, Revision, Article, $location) {

    $scope.create = function() {
        if ($scope.article) {
            $scope.revision={};
            Article.create($scope.article, function(data, headers){
                angular.copy($scope.article, $scope.revision);
                $scope.revision.article_id = data.id;
                $scope.revision.content = data.content;
                $scope.revision.title = data.title;
                Revision.create($scope.revision);
                $location.path('#/wiki/revision/'+$scope.revision.article_id);
            });
        }

        if ($scope.revision && $stateParams.id) {
            $scope.revision.article_id = $stateParams.id;
            Revision.create($scope.revision);
        }
    };

};
```

This is what my controller for adding a post looks like and I'd like to redirect the person to the newly created post. Trouble is - `$location.path` redirects me to `#/home` (index page) every time I try this.

I have tried putting in hard coded links and that didn't work out either. What is wrong with my code and what can I do to mend it?

Comment: Try to remove the `#`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You dont need the "#" actually. That's probably all. ( [link to doc](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/dev_guide.services.%24location) )

Comment: Well that sure was an easy fix. Thanks, mate!

Comment: I'm having a similar problem, expect removing the # is not working for me, Please help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24791938/angular-location-path-not-working-as-expected