# Angular $location.path not working as expected

Tags: angularjs, kendo-treeview, angular-kendo

I am triggering a URL change using $location.path with parameters, however those parameters are NOT getting passed to the target page.

My source page is sidebar.html, and my target page is dashboard.html.

In my sidebar.html I render a Kendo UI treeview widget as follows :

```
<span id="treeview" kendo-tree-view="tree" 
            style="color:white;"
            k-template="vm.treeItemTemplate"
            k-options="vm.treeOptions"
            k-data-source="vm.reportsTree"
            k-on-change="vm.onTreeSelect(kendoEvent)">
 </span>
```

and in my sidebar.js I set **vm.treeItemTemplate** with a **click event**:

```
vm.treeItemTemplate = "<a href='\' ng-click='vm.treeItemClick(this)'> {{dataItem.text}} </a>";
```

then once I click on the treeview item in the browser, I trigger the vm.treeItemClick event to change the URL and eimit the "reptname" parameter:

```
vm.treeItemClick = function (item) {
        console.log("tree view clicked !");
        $location.path('/index.html').search({reptname:'MTM'});
}
```

This is quite painful, and I would appreciate some advice.

I need use the Kendo treeview object in my left nav bar to allow the user to select a variety of report options, which in turn will redirect to the dashboard.html with specific "reptname" parameter values.

Now when I break on $location.path() inside **sidebar.js** (using Chrome dev tools), I clearly see the correct URL property on the $location object.

```
$location
LocationHashbangUrl {$$protocol: "http", $$host: "localhost", $$port: 49479, $$parse:  function,       $$compose: function…}
$$absUrl: "http://localhost:49479/index.html#/index.html?reptname=MTM"
$$host: "localhost"
$$parse: function (url) {
$$path: "/index.html"
$$protocol: "http"
$$replace: false
$$rewrite: function (url) {
$$search: Object
$$url: "/index.html?reptname=MTM"
__proto__: Object
```

However, once it's REDIRECTED to dashboard.html (which is defined in my routes as url:"/"), I DO NOT see the parameter list in the $location object, nor in the $routeParams object.

This is where I'm stuck !

----- UPDATE -------

When I manually refresh the index.html page with parameters, the $location object contains the parameters.

ex/ URL: [Link entered manually](http://index.html#/?reptname='MTM'&userid=5567)

However if I redirect from sidebar.js using `$location.path('/index.html').search({reptname:'MTM'});` , I get nothing !

Answer (score 1):

If you see the parameter in the console but not in your executing code, it might be because Chrome tends to evaluate the console.log with a bit of delay, enought for the async requests to finish and have the data populated, therefor it's not a reliable way of debugging.

Can you listen for the $viewContentLoaded event to be fired and then check the path? That is the view is fully loaded and all variables should be set (including $location.path())

Comment: The treeview is rendered in sidebar.html, and when a treeview item is clicked, I then redirect to dashboard.html. It does indeed redirect; however, the dashboard.js controller never sees the parameters. So I ONLY see the parameter when I debug inside sidebar.js. But when I get to dashboard.js debugging, $location does not show any parameters. I'm stumped !

Comment: $viewContentLoaded didn't make a difference, but thanks for the suggestion. It turns out the only thing that works is $location.url() as in `$location.url('index.html#/?reptname=MTM');` but I don't like because the $location.$$search service is empty. I have to use .$$hash and .split() the parameters list to be useful.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not getting any real answers on this issue, so I ended up solving it this way:

In the Source page, sidebar.js, I have defined the treeview's onSelect event() :

```
 function onTreeSelect(e) {
        vm.selectedReport = e.sender._current.text();          
        $location.url('index.html#/?reptname=' + vm.selectedReport);            
    }
```

and on the target page, dashboard.js i read the query string using the hash() method:

```
  vm.reptNameParam = $location.$$hash.split("=");
```

It seems that $location.url() is the ONLY way I can successfully redirect with a parameters list. Using $location.path() does NOT work for me; meaning, I cannot read the query string in my target page using $location.hash() or any other method as it returns an empty string.